# SQLAlchemy multi-table mapping insert not update on attribute change

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an entity called a Report which points to a report stored in some repository, and those repository can have versioning, therefore the reports have an optional version.

I am now trying to track the reports in SQL via SQLalchemy. Because one report title can have several versions I wanted to [map the entity over two tables](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables), one for the report identification (title and other data I do not include here for simplicity) and one for report versions which reference a report (again plus other data not included here).

I have managed all the above in the following code. But now, I am blocked by the fact that setting the `Report.version` to a newer version causes an update of `report_version` and not the insertion of a new version, which means I'll only ever track one version.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, \
    create_engine, join, select, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, column_property, registry

mapper_registry = registry()

@dataclass
class Report:
    title: str
    version: str | None = field(default=None)  # versioning is optional

report = Table(
    "report",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("report_pk", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("title", String(35), nullable=False),
)

report_version = Table(
    "report_version",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("version_pk", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("report_fk", ForeignKey("report.report_pk"), nullable=False),
    Column("version_id", String(1024), nullable=True),
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Report,
    report.join(report_version),
    properties={
        "id": column_property(report.c.report_pk, report_version.c.report_fk),
        "version": report_version.c.version_id,
    },
)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True, future=True)

mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

# setting attribute causes ORM to update `report_update`
r1 = Report(title="r1", version="a")
session.add(r1)
session.flush()  # flush r1a
r1.version = "b"
session.flush()  # flush r1b

# this is what I would like to achieve
r2 = Report(title="r2", version=".1")
session.add(r2)
session.flush()  # flush r2.1
session.execute(
    text(
        "INSERT INTO report_version (report_fk, version_id) VALUES (:report_id, '.2')"
    ),
    {"report_id": r2.id},
)
session.flush()  # flush r2.2

session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM report")).all()  # r1 and r2
session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM report_version")).all()  # b, .1 and .2

session.execute(select(Report)).scalars().all()  # r1b, r2.1 and r2.2

session.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did not manage the behaviour I wanted over two different tables but went with the simpler [SCD type 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row), and keep adding rows as the report gets updated, which in the SQLAlchemy documentation is found at [Versioning using Temporal Rows](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_rows).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import (Boolean, Column, DateTime, Integer, String, Table,
                        create_engine, event, select, text)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, attributes, make_transient, registry

mapper_registry = registry()

@dataclass
class Report:
    title: str
    version: str | None = field(default=None)  # versioning is optional

report = Table(
    "report",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("title", String(35), nullable=False),
    Column("version_id", String(1024), nullable=True),
    Column("created_at", DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow),
    Column("current_flag", Boolean, nullable=False, index=True, default=True),
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Report, report, properties={"version": report.c.version_id}
)

# SCD II handling for Report
@event.listens_for(Session, "before_flush")
def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    for instance in session.dirty:
        if any((
            not isinstance(instance, Report),
            not session.is_modified(instance),
            not attributes.instance_state(instance).has_identity,
        )):
            continue
        # unset current flag on previous instance
        session.query(Report).filter_by(id=instance.id).update(
            values={"current_flag": False}, synchronize_session=False
        )
        # make instance transient
        make_transient(instance)
        # remove id and created_at since new ones will be created on add
        instance.id = None
        instance.created_at = None
        # re-add to session with new id and version
        session.add(instance)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True, future=True)

mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

# setting attribute causes ORM to update `report_update`
r1 = Report(title="r1", version="a")
session.add(r1)
session.flush()  # flush r1a
r1.version = "b"
session.flush()  # flush r1b

session.execute(select(Report)).scalars().all()  # r1a, r1b
session.execute(select(Report).filter_by(current_flag=True)).scalars().all()  # r1b

session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM report")).all()

session.close()
```